# How to view Windows PC connected to LAN?

Tags: networking, samba, windows-xp

In my LAN, there are 4 PCS. My PC is Ubuntu, others are Windows XP SP2. To share files between us, I installed Samba. In the network places, i can see others PC as well as mine. But when i click on it, it shows a popup "Unable to retrieve the share list from server". I dont know how to access them. I couldn't see even my PC in the network folders. It say the same above message.
Previously i successfully shared files with the same Ubuntu, same samba, same config.

Please tell me to trace the solution. From where i have to check.

Comment: have you restarted the system?

Comment: Do you try to access them by their hostname or IP? Do you get the same result by both methods?
Have you checked the firewall settings in the WinXP machines?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are shutting the machines down regularly, and, without a domain controller, you are unable to establish what is known as a [master browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Master_Browser).  What I would suggest is setting up one machine as your master browser, which is easiest in Samba (see [here](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/NetworkBrowsing.html)) and leaving it on all the time.  I have a Linux based NAS device I have designated as my master browser and I never have an issue with share lists.

Answer (score 1):

If you're after a specific folder on the XP machines, make sure that you have "shared" it. Right click on the folder and select "Sharing and Security". Select "Share this folder" and it should show up when you click on the machine in network places.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file browser and at the location bar type this: `smb://ip-of-samba-server/shared_dir`. Make relevant changes to the command and it should work.